# Rendered imaged has weird shadows

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I've got a sphere with a texture and a material and I'm using blender render. This is how it looks in material view.

[[image]]

And this is how the rendered image looks.

[[image]]

What am I doing wrong?

Heres my .blend file : http://www.mediafire.com/download/gly7535pswrnryj/problem.blend

Note : Im posting the blend file because I've got an integrated graphics card and I've heard blender has got some issues with these. So maybe it works for you, and its just my computer.

Comment: I dont think thats the same problem @stacker

Comment: @VinnieH01 I just inspected your .blend - you have 2 meshes (spheres) on top of each other. One textured and one pink. It is the same problem as in the duplicate.

Comment: but how do i fix it?/Remove the pink mesh? @Jerryno

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate just because it's a Z-fighting problem. The circumstances leading up to the Z-fighting appear to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 spheres on top of each other - one textured, one pink.

To move them apart select 1 vertex in edit-mode and then select all connected to it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. This will select only 1 sphere so they can be separated.

You can also hide selected with <kbd>H</kbd> and unhide with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> so you don't have to move the mesh.

Delete the one you don't want(pink probably).

The 2 spheres were there probably because it was a game-engine model with single-sided polygons - so the textured sphere was for outside and the pink for inside surface. The renderer will render surface from both sides and they are z-fighting.

Answer (score 1):

Found your problem.
You created multiple overlapping spheres in edit mode, so it looks like one object but it has the geometry of many spheres.

Try to delete a face and you'll notice you have to do it around 4 times before it actually disappears from the sphere.

The artefact is due to Z-fighting.