# Problem with texturing UV map

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

My model texture is for some reason "glicthing", whenever i move the camera it randomly "glitches" in different places, like if it had 2 overlapping textured faces, but theres only one.

What am i doing wrong?

[edit] I had the mirror modifier  on, it was mirroring my texture and overlapping with itself causing the "glitching" effect

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34417/rendered-imaged-has-weird-shadows/34423#34423

Comment: Didn't worked, i don't have any overlapping faces, much less objects.

Comment: can you upload your file? you can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Edit your question and paste the link to it.

Comment: Nevermind i found the problem